# Samsung S8 is stuck on start logo after flashing

Tags: samsung, rooting, twrp, odin

I know this question has been posted but none of the solutions is working for me.
I flashed official ROM using Odin on my S8 950FD. The process was smooth, the phone rebooted, installed update (blue screen), erased, rebooted again and then stuck on logo. I waited for a long time, then pressed Power + Vol down buttons. As soon as it turned off, I pressed Power + Bixby + Vol up. I was in stock recovery. Wiped cache and data, rebooted again, same result. One thing I see is my **dm-verity verification** status is **failed** in stock recovery.

I went to download mode again, my KG state was showing Prenormal. I tried flashing TWRP, OFRP recoveries but of course got Official Binaries blah blah error. I tried flashing stock firmware again and again but no luck. All I can see on my phone is either Samsung Galaxy S8 or I can go to recovery or download mode. The phone will never boot.

I tried Miracle Box 2.82 cracked version as well, but still no luck, it shows TOKEN SIZE TOO BIG or something like that.

Any chance I can get my phone working and alive again??

I have tried flashing many UC-9 official ROMs but still failed and I am on Samsung logo screen. I love my phone and don't want to loose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got my phone working again. It's got a new life but there is no magic bullet. Luckily, my brother had an exact similar phone with damaged display panel and he had thrown it somewhere in the house. I accidentally found it and got its board replaced with my bricked phone and viola, my S8 is now up again in around 8USD of cost.

One thing I would like to add, I didn't look form other software solutions. There could be one but once I found a dead phone, I stopped looking for it.